# Does modifying elements in first collection that is backing another, change elements in second collection?

Tags: java, multithreading, collections

In Java [Collection](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html) doc we read

```
public static <T> Collection<T> synchronizedCollection(Collection<T> c)
```

> Returns a synchronized (thread-safe) collection backed by the
>   specified collection.

Does it mean that changing (altering, removing, adding) elements in the first collection alter also a second collection even if second is immutable?

Comment: Yes, that's what "backed by" means.  But if the second collection is truly immutable, then attempting to change the first collection will fail.

Comment: Also, there's no point in synchronizing an immutable collection.

Comment: The returned collection is a *view* into the other. An unmodifiable wrapper does not support changes *through* the view, but reflects the changes made on the original, backing collection. But the method you’ve posted, is not unmodifiable but *synchronized*. Modifications are possible through the view and the backing collection, but when you modify the backing collection directly, you break the thread safety.